# AWS Lambda Opencv ("Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, aws-lambda

Trying to make an import of cv2 in aws lambda. Tried to install it with a layer with an arn from this link: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/deployments/python3.8/arns/eu-west-3.csv

But i get an error and have trouble to solve it:
"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libgthread-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

My lambda works with python 3.8 also. I also tried python 3.6 and 3.7.

Does anybody have a fonctionnal Klayer arn for opencv ? Or a usefull tutorial to make it.

```
import json
import cv2 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Was searching for an answer and found the solution here: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/issues/115

It requires both the opencv module and libgthread-2.0.so.0 to work.

Go to https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers again and look for the "libgthread-so" package. Add the libgthread-so package as a new layer and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also on the same error but as @jen said that you must have libgthread-so to make this work

Add this to your lambda layer

```
arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:770693421928:layer:Klayers-python38-libgthread-so:1
```

Hope it helps